# Excel automatic reduced print size - all print size change to small, all positions are wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, scaling, margins

My company have one file shared for users, it provided by another company and set the print area NOT allow to change (password protected)

User A, B using same configuration computer, same OS and office, same printer driver, printer and work with same file

- When User A and B open this excel file on their computers you can see the print area is bigger than A4
- When they print, User A and User B choose Fit Sheet On One Page, it should print out only one page, but already can see User A print area is smaller
- But, when User A choose NO SCALING, it should print out 2 pages, but NOT, still print out 1 page, User B also choose NO SCALING, shows will print out 2 page, because the print area is bigger than A4, that is normal.

The problem is USER A Excel automatic reduced her print size, no matter she choose what scale 50%, 70% or 99% always smaller than other users, and always print out wrong margin because her Excel reduced the print size

I tried all I can try, paper size, page break, column width........all same. Then I tried using WORD on user A computer, all back to normal, it looks like only Excel problem.

**The most wired is USER A click PAGE LAYOUT view, it seems normal (62 rows), BUT when she click print preview then back to PAGE LAYOUT view changed to 66 rows)**

Any hints to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

But... your two users have two different printers selected -- *Microsoft Print to PDF* vs some Canon model.  (I'm looking at pics 5 and 6 right now.)  Please note: The previews (and the printouts) are recomputed depending on what printer you select.  For example, different printers have different minimum margins.  Maybe if you get both users to select *Print to PDF* they will look the same.  I would try that.

Furthermore, the icons for the print settings are different -- look at the "Collated" one, look at the "Print" button.  This tells me that probably the Excel versions or (more likely) the OS versions are different.

Comment: OK, I tried at same OS and same printer, the problem is same.

Comment: So, all of `File > Page setup` is unavailable to you?

Comment: Yes available,  all tried but fail, I am now focusing on why 62 row -> 66 row after print preview